# Java returns Date object to Flex incorrectly

Tags: java, apache-flex, date, deserialization, graniteds

I am using Flex,GraniteDS and Javа. 
Flex is sending Date correctly in Daylight saving time for example "September 10 10:00:00 UTC-7", but after all I am receiving the same date but in Standard time "September 10 11:00:00:00 UTC-8". As I understand GraniteDS is deserializing the Java Date incorrectly.
Any ideas how to work this out?

Comment: What is the 'I' in this statement: "I am receiving the same date but in Standard time"?   do you mean the Java Server?  Or the Flex Client?  Or something else?

Comment: He's prob referring to the Java VM. He could be using a very old version of Java, which hasn't been patched to address DST time changes implemented a few years back. (A particularly nasty "bug" since it only causes problems for a few specific weeks a year!)

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is a difference in timezones between your flash client and your server.
Suppose that:
GMT + X: timezone of your server
GMT + Y: timezone of your client

The correct way to fix your problem is to define a fixed timezone on your marshalling format (XML, AMF...) and convert your dates at the correct places to this timezone.

For instance:

When you send a message from your client to the server:
Client GMT + Y -> Client side conversion of date to GMT + 0 -> AMF GMT + 0 -> Server-side conversion from GMT + 0 to GMT + X -> Server GMT + X

When the server sends a date to the client:
Server GMT + X -> Server side conversion to GMT + 0 -> AMF GMT + 0 -> Client side conversion to GMT + Y -> Client GMT + Y

With Granite, it means there are 2 fixes to do: modifying the Groovy templates for client side conversion of date to GMT+0, and adding a Converter on the server side (Date converted to Date but with timezone conversion).
I have already done this patch on many Flex projects now, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but I had a similar problem with Flex dates a couple years ago.
I was getting a table from a SQL database to a flex swf via ColdFusion. 
I noticed that the date is converted from the timezone of the ColdFusion / Database server to the timezone in which the Flex app is running. Maybe this is the problem?

I solved it (though it added a significant overhead) to adding the timezone difference and compensating for timezone at the flex end

Answer (score 0):

We handled this by avoiding the problem, formatted all dates as strings when transmitted between layers.

Answer (score 0):

No, Granite isn't doing anything incorrectly, it's built-in Flash time conversions. The link below clarifies. In some apps (probably more globalized "Flash-y" apps, than centralized "Enterprise-y" apps) this is desired behavior, but often it's not.

For a workaround, the link below has one solution and mentions a few of the other alternatives out there.

http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2008/02/05/flex-local-datestime-transfer-issue

I generally prefer the send-as-String solution mezmo mentioned, but of course requirements & integrations (ORM...) will drive the decision.

(This type of problem will generally exist in any technology which serializes "date/time" objects instantiated in different time zones. If you think of a time object in terms of milliseconds, a new Date() instantiating to the current time will be set to a different number of milliseconds since the "birth" of UNIX, depending on time zone.)